# Why is this useRef value undefined in this setInterval?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, use-ref

Why is the reference to `swiss` `undefined` in this `setInterval`?

On every iteration, the value of `swiss` is passed in.

```
export default function cheese() {
    const swiss = useRef("Jarlsberg")
    const myInterval = useRef()
    myInterval.current = setInterval ( swiss => {
        console.log(swiss) //-> undefined
        console.log(swiss.current) //-> Error b/c undefined has no properties
    }, 997)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `setInterval` incorrectly. In your arrow function, you have `swiss` as a *parameter*, not an *argument* (value that you are passing). When `setInterval` calls your arrow function, it does not *pass any arguments*, hence why `swiss` is `undefined`.

Edit: You might also be "hiding" the real `swiss` value with your parameter's name.  With my testing, `swiss` is available inside the `setInterval` call if you remove your parameter, or change its name.

```js
export default function cheese() {
    const swiss = useRef("Jarlsberg")
    const myInterval = useRef();
    myInterval.current = setInterval ( () => { // note the change from `swiss` to an empty ().
        console.log(swiss) //-> exists!
        console.log(swiss.current) //-> Jarlsberg
    }, 997)
}
```